# How can i put page loader in laravel controller's function?

Tags: php, laravel

I am routing my user's to third party URL.

Now whenever they are routing there is a blank page or default tab which is open is displaying, but they are actually  redirecting on that URL.

What i want to do like as soon as that routing first function called i need to put page loader there so user's come to know that they are redirecting.

How can i do that in controller ? I can load view file i know but after that remaining code will not work of that function.

Guide me over here.

Thanks in advance.

I tried loading view file but it was not run remaining code.

Comment: Can you not simply redirect users to a 'holding page' where a spinner is shown, along with whatever else you like. When this page loads, you can run a simple javascript or meta redirect to the actual destination?

Answer (score 0):

Simply direct your users to a holding page, and then run some simple javascript redirects to get them to their actual destination.

**app/routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('redirect', 'YourController@redirect');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/YourController.php**

```
public function redirect(Request $request) {
    $url = $request['url'];
    return view('holding-page', compact('url'));
}
```

**resources/views/holding-page.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Redirect the user to where they want to go after 3 seconds.
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace("{{ $url }}");
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

---

Make sure you url encode any urls that you pass as a query string parameter.
`https://yoursite.com/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com`

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks i know this way i can achieve my  goal , but in controller function there is my some code that must be executed after that execution user's can able to see loader page. But my question is during that calculation they  are not seeing anything.

Comment: Any resolution to that?