# Laravel how to redirect to a loading page after login

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I am making a Laravel Project for school, it's a web chat app, I wanted to make it  when you login it redirects you to my animated loading page and then after some seconds, it would redirect to the home route.

[image: Login]

[image: Loader]

[image: Home]

Login Controller :

changed from  `protected $redirectTo = "/home";`
to:

```
protected $redirectTo = "/loader";
```

What would be the next step i am lost.

Comment: The animated page is comming from?

Comment: The animated page is in views

Comment: does your question look similar to [How can i put page loader in laravel controller's function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690369/how-can-i-put-page-loader-in-laravel-controllers-function)

Comment: Can i just do this? protected $redirectTo = "/loader"; and then in the loading page javascript make a function that redirects to the /home after some seconds? Is this correct?